# User input that is a command and file name, create file name and store linkedlist contents

Tags: c, file, pointers, printing

The knapsack program im attempting to make has a user interface that takes in commands, one of them is save and load from a file. Im wondering how you go about creating a file from user input when this command is given all in one line and then storing the contents of the linked list into this file and then being able to load it and print it out later. Part of whats tripping me up is getting it all in the same input and then printing the contents into that user defined file name. How can this be done, should i be using fopen and fprintf? Also if the filename given is something like /rootfile then it should be flagged as being unable to save to that file since its a directory. They should also be binary files.

**knapsack-shell.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "knapsack.c"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
void removeSpaces(char *str1)
{
    char *str2;
    str2=str1;
    while (*str2==' ') str2++;
    if (str2!=str1) memmove(str1,str2,strlen(str2)+1);
}

int main()
{
    listitemptr k2 = NULL;
    char input[100];
    char command;
    int i, returnval = 0;
    char filename[250];
    char userfile[260];

    char *error;

   for (;;) {
       FILE* pf = NULL;
        fprintf(stdout, "> ");
        if (!fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin))
            break;
        i = strspn(input, " \t\n");  /* skip blanks */
        command = input[i++];

        if (command == 'q' && input[i] == '\n')
            break;
        if (command == 'p') {
            KnapsackPrint(&k2);
            continue;
        }
        if (command == 'a') {
            int item;
            if (sscanf(input + i, "%i", &item) != 1) {
                error = input + i;
                removeSpaces(error);
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Bad item \"%s\"\n", strtok(input + i, "\n"));

                continue;
            }
            KnapsackAdd(&k2, item);
            KnapsackPrint(&k2);
            continue;
        }
        if (command == 'r') {

            int item;
            if (sscanf(input + i, "%i", &item) != 1) {
                error = input + i;
                removeSpaces(error);
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Bad item \"%s\"\n", strtok(input + i, "\n"));
                continue;
            }

            if(KnapsackRemove(&k2, item) == -1){
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: item %d does not exist in knapsack\n", item);
                continue;
            }else{
            KnapsackPrint(&k2);
            continue;
            }

        }
        if(command == 's'){
            if(( pf = fopen(input + i, "a")) != NULL){
                error = input + i;
                removeSpaces(error);
                fprintf(pf, "%s", KnapsackPrint2(&k2));
                fprintf(stdout, "stored in file \"%s\"\n", strtok(input+i, "\n"));
            }
            continue;
        }
        if(command == 'l'){
            continue;
        }
        else{
        fprintf(stderr, "unknown command: %s", input);
        fprintf(stdout, "> ");
        }

    }
    return returnval;
}
```

**knapsack.c**

```
#include "knapsack.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

listitemptr KnapsackAdd(listitemptr *knapsack, int item){
   if(*knapsack==NULL){//empty list
       listitemptr newest= malloc(sizeof(struct listitem));
       newest->item=item;
       newest->count=1;
       newest->next=NULL;
       *knapsack = newest;
       return newest;
   }else{
       listitemptr current=*knapsack;
       listitemptr prev=NULL;
       while(current!=NULL){
           if(current->item == item){
               current->count=current->count+1;
               break;
           }else if(current -> item > item){
               listitemptr new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct listitem));
               new_node-> item = item;
               new_node-> count= 1;
               new_node-> next = current;
               if(prev != NULL ){
                   prev->next = new_node;
               }else {
                   *knapsack = new_node;

               }
               break;

           }
           prev=current;
           current=current->next;
       }
       if(current==NULL){
           listitemptr newest= malloc(sizeof(struct listitem));
           newest->item=item;
           newest->count=1;
           newest->next=NULL;
           prev->next=newest;
           return newest;
       }
       return current;
   }
}

int KnapsackRemove(listitemptr *knapsack, int item){
   if(*knapsack==NULL)
       return -1;
   listitemptr present=*knapsack;
   listitemptr previous=NULL;

   while(present!=NULL){
       if(present->item==item){
           if(present->count>1){
               present->count=present->count-1;
           }else{
               if(previous==NULL){ //delete at head
                   *knapsack=present->next;
               }else{
                   previous->next=present->next;
                   free(present);
               }
           }
           break;
       }
       previous=present;
       present=present->next;
   }

   return 0;
}

void KnapsackPrint(const listitemptr *knapsack){
   if(*knapsack==NULL)
       printf("knapsack: \n");
   else{
       listitemptr temp=*knapsack;
       printf("knapsack:");
       while(temp!=NULL){
           if((temp->next) == NULL){
               printf(" %d (%d)", temp->item, temp->count);
               break;
           }else{
           printf(" %d (%d),",temp->item,temp->count);
           temp=temp->next;
         }

       }
       printf("\n");
   }
}

unsigned int KnapsackItemCount(const listitemptr *knapsack, int item){
   if(*knapsack==NULL)
       return 0;
   listitemptr temp=*knapsack;
   while(temp!=NULL){
       if(temp->item==item)
           return temp->count;
       temp=temp->next;
   }
   return 0;  
}

unsigned int KnapsackSize(const listitemptr *knapsack){

   if(*knapsack==NULL){

       return 0;
   }

   listitemptr temp=*knapsack;
   unsigned int sum=0;
   while(temp!=NULL){
       sum+=temp->count;
       temp=temp->next;
    }
   return sum;


}

listitemptr KnapsackPrint2(const listitemptr *knapsack){
   if(*knapsack==NULL)
       printf("knapsack: \n");
   else{
       listitemptr temp=*knapsack;
       printf("knapsack:");
       while(temp!=NULL){
           if((temp->next) == NULL){
               printf(" %d (%d)", temp->item, temp->count);
               break;
           }else{
           printf(" %d (%d),",temp->item,temp->count);
           temp=temp->next;
         }

       }
       printf("\n");
       return temp;
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't worry about explicitly checking of the file is a directory.  `fopen` will fail in such a case, so `if( (file = fopen(path, mode)) == NULL ) { perror(path); ... }` is sufficient.

Comment: oh thats awesome i didnt know fopen had that capability. How would i go about getting the file name from the user and then printing the contents into said file using fopen? i would put it in 'w' mode right? KnapsackPrint correctly prints the contents of the file but its not possible to save its output into the file explicitly is it?

Comment: You need to decide how you want to store the content.  That is, you need to serialize the data (json, avro, protobuf, ...or design your own serialization).  Since you're ignoring whitespace in the data, you can probably store the list one entry per line (eg, you're defining your own serialization method).  Yes, `fprintf` is probably a good way to go.

Comment: But perhaps the issue you're running into is that your attempt to save the data is truncating the data already in the file.  You might want mode `"a"` to append data when it is written rather than discarding the content already in the file.

Comment: could possibly something like `fprintf(filename, "%s", KnapsackPrint(&k2));` work?

Comment: You could change the API to make that workable.  To do that `KnapsackPrint` would have to return a `char *`.  Probably you want KnapsackPrint to take a `FILE *` argument, and pass it either `stdout` or your user's file.

Comment: hmmm okay so trying something out gonna update my code now, was making another print function that would do basically the same thing as knapsackprint but return a char pointer. issue im running into is in the fprintf statement to write the contents to the file im not sure how to format that so it prints correctly since %s doesnt do the trick since im returning a struct listitem *